# Groovy Eclipse compiler plugin for maven not compiling anything

Tags: eclipse, maven, groovy

I'm trying to understand the correct setup of a Java and Groovy project in Maven, compiling the source files with groovy-eclipse-compiler.

According to the [plugin site](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven), if you have files in `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` the compiler should find both Java and Groovy by default.

Setting up the `build` like the example makes `target/classes` empty.

```
<build>
...
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
      <!-- set verbose to be true if you want lots of uninteresting messages -->
      <!-- <verbose>true</verbose> -->
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0-01</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
</build>
```

The only way I found to make it work was to use the `build-helper-maven-plugin`. This is the option used by the Archetype too:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.groovy \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=groovy-eclipse-quickstart \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.2-SNAPSHOT \
    -DgroupId=foo \
    -DartifactId=bar \
    -Dversion=1 \
    -DinteractiveMode=false \
    -DarchetypeRepository=https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/snapshots/
```

So, it's the page outdated? Isn't enough have Java files in the src folder?

Comment: My simple updated solution to this: use Gradle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm able to get this to work.  Here is what I did:

1. create the archetype as you did above.
2. edit the pom.xml to the file below
3. mv everything from src/main/groovy to src/main/java and the same for the tests.
4. remove the empty groovy dirs
5. rename all *.java files to *.groovy
6. mvn clean compile
7. I get some expected compile errors due to differences in Java vs groovy syntax, but all groovy files are recognized.

Does this work for you?  If not what is different?

Here is the pom file I am using:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>foo</groupId>
  <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <name>bar Groovy Eclipse Maven Java App</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0-01</version>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1-01</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

---

**EDIT**

Since I misunderstood the actual question, and you do want to keep the files separate, then there are 2 options:

1. using the build-helper-plugin as you have done
2. Use the groovy-eclipse-compiler mojo:

> ```
>   <plugin>
>     <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
>     <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
>     <version>2.7.0-01</version>
>     <extensions>true</extensions>
>   </plugin>
>
> </build>
> ```

This is all described on the [groovy-eclipse-compiler](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Groovy-Eclipse+compiler+plugin+for+Maven) page.

Comment: "mv everything from src/main/groovy to src/main/java and the same for the tests". Probably this is the difference. I wanted to keep different folders for groovy and java files.

Comment: Oh...that's not what I gathered from your question.  When you said "if you have files in src/main/java and src/test/java the compiler should find both Java and Groovy by default.", I thought you wanted all files in the Java directories.

Comment: As described in the plugin page, if you want to keep the folders separate, then there are 2 options.  I'll edit my answer above.

Comment: I may misunderstood the docs, but the mojo section says: "You only need this approach if your project has an empty src/main/java or src/test/java." I have java files in both folders.

Comment: Hmmm...works for me with files in src/main/java|groovy and src/test/java|groovy and not using build-helper, or the mojo. Maybe there's something else going on.  Any chance you can get me a copy of the project you are using?  You can raise an issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE and attach it there.

Comment: Damn! I tried to isolate the issue in a new project and it didn't occur, and since I don't have the original file anymore I will close this question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Well, it's not out of the question that there is a real bug here.  If you ever see the problem again, do raise an issue.

Comment: I think I hit this again. If there's nothing new to compile and you run `clean compile`, the target folder will be empty.